# Gas leaking from this tube,wondering what exactly this tube is

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, leak, valve

[image: tube]

Hello, I'm fairly new to mechanics of motorcycle(riding for 2 years but never tried to repair it myself till last month).

As I noticed I am using way more gas than usual and there was gas odor, then I tried to spot where the leakage was and found out that it was this tube shown in the photo. It's leaking directly on the hot engine. After days long of research about causes of leakages, what I want to learn is;

1. What this tube supposed to do along with other two tubes connected to the valve?
2. Could it be something like an overflow of fuel causing overpressure on this tube, resulting in leakage, or is it simply the tube got old?

Will post further pics if necessary, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! From the way it runs, it looks like it's for the reserve (last little bit of gas in the tank).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So,would that mean if the valve isn't on reserve, would this tube still leak?

Comment: I'm not completely versant in motorcycles, but yes. I believe the hose has gas at it as long as there is fuel in the tank. I'd suspect you'll need to replace the hose, but you might be able to get away with a small clamp around the end of the hose at the valve. If there's not enough room, you can take a bit of wire (like lacing wire), wrap it around it once, then twisting it to seal the hose to the valve (not too tight, though).

Comment: You should not ride the bike anymore until the leak is stopped. Petrol burns easily, and the engine gets hot. You don't want to be suddenly riding a fireball, it's messy, and usually painful.
@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the way it runs, it looks like it's for the reserve (last little bit of gas in the tank).

> So,would that mean if the valve isn't on reserve, would this tube still leak?

I'm not completely versant in motorcycles, but yes. I believe the hose has gas at it as long as there is fuel in the tank. I'd suspect you'll need to replace the hose, but you might be able to get away with a small clamp around the end of the hose at the valve. If there's not enough room, you can take a bit of wire (like lacing wire), wrap it around it once, then twisting it to seal the hose to the valve (not too tight, though).

If it's not the hose itself which is leaking, it might be the valve. I think the only way to fix it would be to replace it (obviously depending on *how* it's leaking, though).

Comment: I think this is on the money. @Ozan, check where the leak is actually coming from, it could be running down the fuel hose from the tank rather than coming from the hose or valve. You can use a bit of paper towel on a stick to trace the source of the leak.

Comment: @GdD - Great point about it running down the hose.